# Посчитайте сколько часов занимают занятия по расписанию. Сгруппируйте результат по предмету и классу. Округлите до одного знака после запятой

Tags: mysql

https://sql-academy.org/ru/sandbox - вот ссылка на базу, таблица Schedule

Пробовал вот так:

```
SELECT Class.name AS class_name, Subject.name AS subject, TIMEDIFF(end_pair, start_pair) AS spent_hours FROM Subject JOIN Schedule ON Subject.id = Schedule.subject JOIN Class ON Schedule.class = Class.id JOIN Timepair ON Schedule.number_pair = Timepair.id
GROUP BY class_name, subject, spent_hours
```

Но это немного не то, что нужно. Так же не понимаю, почему требует группировку по всем полям, когда есть функция расчета даты.

Comment: *не понимаю, почему требует группировку по всем полям* Группировка должна быть по всем ИСХОДНЫМ полям, которые использованы в списке вывода не в аргументе агрегатной функции. *Пробовал вот так* Расскажите подробно, какую логику Вы заложили в этот запрос. Ибо это не "немного не то", а "близко не лежало". Задание вообще-то подразумевает, что отдельные часы надо суммировать в разрезе предмета и класса.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT subject.name as subject, class.name as class_name, ROUND
((SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, start_pair, end_pair )))/60, 1) AS spent_hours
FROM Schedule
JOIN Timepair ON Schedule.number_pair = timepair.id
JOIN Subject ON Schedule.subject = Subject.id
JOIN Class ON Schedule.class = class.id
GROUP BY subject.id, class.name
ORDER BY subject.name, class_name
```